# Profile, _raw and _json of passport libraries

Tags: authentication, passport.js

I use `passport.js`, `passport-google`, `passport-facebook`, `passport-microsoft`, etc. They all have the same signature of `loginSuccessfully`:

```
Passport.prototype.loginSuccessfully = function (accessToken, refeshToken, profile, done) { ... ... }
```

And `profile` often contains `_raw` and `_json`. I realize that sometimes they don't have exactly the same fields or information. Eg, certain information may exist in `_raw`, but not in the basis of `profile`; field names may change as well.

Could anyone tell me, in general, which one is directly sent by social media sites, and which one is generated by passport libraries?

In other words, which part could I totally rely on?

Comment: Did you finally figured it out?